# How to convert microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset to Date in Anorm?

Tags: sql-server, anorm

I developing a project developing with Scala, Play framework 2.3.8, Anorm and works with MS SQL database.

Here the code:

```
val repeatedCardsQuery = SQL("Execute Forms.getListOfRepeatCalls {user}, {cardId}")
DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
  val result = repeatedCardsQuery.on("user" -> user.name, "cardId" -> id)().map(row =>
    Json.obj(
      "Unified_CardNumber" -> row[Long]("scId"),
      "ContentSituation_TypeSituationName" -> row[String]("typeOfEventsName"),
      "Unified_Date" -> row[Date]("creationDate"),
      "InfoPlaceSituation_Address" -> row[String]("address"),
      "DescriptionSituation_DescriptionSituation" -> row[Option[String]]("description")
    )
  ).toList
  Ok(response(id, "repeats", result))
}
```

And it gives me runtime error:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: Left(TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 2015-02-14 15:38:15.4089363 +03:00: class microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset to Date for column ColumnName(.creationDate,Some(creationDate))))]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:205) [play_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:202) [play_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33) [scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Left(TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 2015-02-14 15:38:15.4089363 +03:00: class microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset to Date for column ColumnName(.creationDate,Some(creationDate))))
    at anorm.MayErr$$anonfun$get$1.apply(MayErr.scala:34) ~[anorm_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at anorm.MayErr$$anonfun$get$1.apply(MayErr.scala:33) ~[anorm_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:97) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at anorm.MayErr.get(MayErr.scala:33) ~[anorm_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at anorm.Row$class.apply(Row.scala:57) ~[anorm_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
[error] application - Left(TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 2015-02-14 15:38:15.4089363 +03:00: class microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset to Date for column ColumnName(.creationDate,Some(creationDate))))
```

Actually, error occurs in this line:

```
"Unified_Date" -> row[Date]("creationDate"),
```

How solve that problem, and convert microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset to Date in this case?

Comment: What if you use `"Unified_Date" -> new Date(row[microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset]("creationDate").getTimestamp)`? I know it isn't pretty, but is just to see if it works...

Comment: Also you can try to create a implicit converter like `implicit def MSSQLDTOffset2Date(value : microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset) = new Date(value.getTimestamp)` and see if anorm picks it

Comment: @Salem first variant doesn't work because last changes in anorm require typesafe parameters. more in this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23#Anorm Create implict converter may be works, but how anorm picks it? And where in this code I need to declarate implict converter?

Comment: Usually you would define that in a object and then import that obj whenever you needed it. To test it you can declare it before `repeatedCardsQuery` or any other queris in that file that may need it

Answer (score 1):

A custom column conversion can be added next to your Anorm call (defined or imported in same class/object which needed to support such type).

```scala
import java.util.Date
import microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset
import anorm.Column

implicit def columnToDate: Column[Date] = Column.nonNull { (value, meta) => 
  val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
  value match {
    case ms: DateTimeOffset =>
      Right(ms.getTimestamp)
    case _ => 
      Left(TypeDoesNotMatch(s"Cannot convert $value: ${value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass} to Boolean for column $qualified"))
  }
}
```

> Btw it would be much better to work with DB values represented as JDBC dates (`java.sql.Date` types supported by Anorm).

Comment: I think this is right way. But that code doesn't compile. Idea suggests me: 'Type mismatch, expected: (Any, MetaDataItem) => MayErr[SqlRequestError, NotInferedA], actual: (Any, MetaDataItem) => Unit' starting with '{ (value, meta) ...', and play compiler tells same thing.